# Zsh prompt function doesn't work

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, console, zsh

why it's doesn't work? prompt area is empty and i not have errors.

```
setopt prompt_subst
git_prompt() {
  temp=`git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null | cut -d / -f 3`
  if [ "$temp" != "" ]; then
        RPROMPT='%{$fg_no_bold[green]%}git:($temp%)%{$reset_color%} %{$fg_no_bold[yellow]%}[%1~]%{$reset_color%}'
  else
        RPROMPT='%{$fg_no_bold[yellow]%}[%~]%{$reset_color%}'
  fi
}
RPROMPT='$(git_prompt)'
```

The values of RPROMPT spelled correctly and do not contain errors.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 3):

The function `git_prompt` does not produce any output but sets `RPROMPT` directly. Yet you are then setting `RPROMPT` to the output of `git_prompt`, effectively setting it to an empty string.

Either return the strings instead of setting `RPROMPT` in `git_prompt`.

```
setopt prompt_subst
git_prompt() {
  temp=`git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null | cut -d / -f 3`
  if [ "$temp" != "" ]; then
        return '%{$fg_no_bold[green]%}git:($temp%)%{$reset_color%} %{$fg_no_bold[yellow]%}[%1~]%{$reset_color%}'
  else
        return '%{$fg_no_bold[yellow]%}[%~]%{$reset_color%}'
  fi
}
RPROMPT='$(git_prompt)'
```

Or just set `git_prompt` to be run automatically before printing the prompt:

```
git_prompt() {
  temp=`git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null | cut -d / -f 3`
  if [ "$temp" != "" ]; then
        RPROMPT='%{$fg_no_bold[green]%}git:($temp%)%{$reset_color%} %{$fg_no_bold[yellow]%}[%1~]%{$reset_color%}'
  else
        RPROMPT='%{$fg_no_bold[yellow]%}[%~]%{$reset_color%}'
  fi
}
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd git_prompt
```

---

You might also want to look into [the `vcs_info` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Version-Control-Information), which allows you to generate prompts with version control information without having to do the data retrieval on your own.

Comment: Thank you i used git_prompt works like charm! In case of any needs i was trying to get current change numbers of that branch.

changed the temp like this 
**'temp='git diff --shortstat | sed -e 's/insertions//' -e's/deletions//''**